# How to call a service inside a static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm making an extension class to get user email, but I cannot refer to `ApplicationDbContext` service.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    // private static readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    // static Extensions(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    // {
    //     _dbContext = dbContext;
    // }

    public static string GetUserEmail(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        string email = string.Empty;

        string userid = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
        {
            email = _dbContext.Users.Single(x => x.Id == userid).Email;
        }

        return email;
    }
}
```

Useage:

```
string email = User.GetUserEmail();
```

But static class cannot contain any parameter. Also, I don't want to pass `dbContext` as a parameter to `GetUserEmail` method.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: there is a class for that exact request already I assume using Identity?

Comment: you could ensure the email claim is in the `ClaimsPrincipal` and then read that

Comment: @mvermef Sorry, no need to extract request.

Comment: the recommended way is to do what @Dr.Fre is suggesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the usermanager to get that information

```
// Inject UserManager<IdentityUser> into your controller or service
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User); // pass ClaimsPrincipal
var email = await usermanager.GetEmailAsync(user);
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you use a static initialization method?

```
public class Extensions
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext _dbContext { get; set; }

    public static void Init(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Extensions.Init(dbContext);
var email = User.GetEmail();
```

Comment: It looks good. So, how do you assign to the context on razor page?

Comment: @foo your question makes no mention of Razor anywhere.

Comment: @Amy Sorry for missing that. But that's why I don't want to use the context as a parameter.

Comment: You shouldn't use this in Razor anyway.  Use it in your controller, and pass the data into the Razor view.  Your view should not have any knowledge of your dbcontext.

Comment: Using static fields to store DbContext is wrong on so many level: 1. it beats the purpose of having DI in the first place, 2. it will create a memory leak and/or the dreaded `Object is already disposed` message, since the reference will stay even after  the request has ended